# How can we use “launch Template” in elastic beanstalk using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I cannot find the option for launch template in elastic beanstalk terraform document. Is there any way to use

Comment: Have you written any Terraform yet? It would be good if you could edit your existing question to include a [mcve] that shows what you've done so far and then explain why it doesn't work for you and what you'd prefer. If there's any errors then you should include the full error output in your question too.

Comment: the terraform does not provide the option for launch template in elastic beastalk, how will i create the terraform for it?